# Poor Choice of Prior Answer

Tags: support

My recent question [Are phrases of the form "A <possession> of <name>'s" grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/571983/92922) has been closed as allegedly already having an answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302861/double-possessive-a-friend-of-stevens).

My first issue with this substitution is that, unless one already knows what a double possessive is, one is unlikely to think that this is of any relevance. The second issue is that the only answer to this question is utterly unhelpful: when applied to the specific example I gave in my question, it implies that "a metaphor of Saul's" is a shortened version of "a metaphor of Saul's metaphors", which makes no sense in context.

Furthermore, and rather ironically, this question had itself already been 'closed as duplicate' with respect to a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55355/92922) where one may figure out what the answer to my question is if one reads the various answers. Even so, this question's chosen answer is predicated on a dubious claim of inverse meaning (that is not just my opinion, as shown by the comments) and it is not obvious that there is a clear answer to my question here (i.e. of comparable clarity and directness to the answer posted to my question.)

If my question should be closed as a duplicate, could you at least find one with an answer that clearly works here?

Also, as a general principle, if a question is being closed for having been answered elsewhere, should not the link be to that specific *answer*, rather than the question? As a question may have more than one answer, and some of them may be irrelevant or simply wrong, linking to the question may create ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, it should be linked to a correct answer, rather than to a question. Most questions here are ungrammatical and/or unhelpfully phrased, so that one can't tell what the answer is likely to be from the question. And the answer should be correct, not just selected by an ignorant questioner as the one they liked best. This is yet one more example of the appallingly bad match between the SE Question-Answer dynamic, and the actual facts of English language knowledge worldwide.